# Error installing MDB2 under Pear

Tags: php, installation, pear, mdb2

I am trying to install pear's mdb2 package so I can use mail queue. I enter the following command and get the error below. Any suggestions?

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4>pear install MDB2`

No releases available for package "pear.php.net/MDB2" install failed

*** I have been able to install manually, but can not answer my own question yet.***

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a temporary issue? Could be a bug in the version of PEAR too.

Try:

```
pear upgrade PEAR
pear upgrade-all
pear channel-update pear.php.net
pear install MDB2
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same because of temporary files, so I had to clear pear cache then all worked perfectly. Running on WAMP (Windows)

```
pear clear-cache
pear install -a PackageName
```